# Android EditText LongClick to Paste

Tags: android, paste

My Android mobile phone system language is Chinese,and in other app,the edittext's longClick language is Chinese,but in my developed app,the edittext's longClick language is English.[enter image description here

How can I make edittext's longClick to Paste language to Chinese in my App.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use "android.R.string.paste" as a resource string. It will adjust the language that the phone used. So if the phone language Chinese it will show Chinese, etc.

If you don't want to use "android.R.string.paste" you can also make you own string resource sets to your res/values and specify the countries you want to support

Answer (score 0):

Because I set the locale language in wrong way.

Comment: could you share your solution plz?